# While Loop Iterating Once inside foreach loop php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my code:

```
foreach($to_list as $row)
{
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`='$row' LIMIT 1");
    while($rowx=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo $row['name']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Foreach loop is iterating properly but while loop inside it is iterating only once.
Some suggests that I can use array, but I tried to do so but error;

Output I m getting is(while loop iterating once):

John

---

Output I want is given below:

John

Hrithik

Salman

Comment: You have limt 1 in your query. So it wil only iterate 1 time

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They're deprecated and removed in current versions of PHP. Instead have a look at `mysqli_*` or PDO and _prepared statements_.

Comment: @Michael if I remove limit than also it's iterating only 1 time

Comment: What do you have in your table?

Comment: the table has student name, foreach loop getting ID one by one and while loop should use that id and fetch student name

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`='$row' LIMIT 1
```

Selects exatly 1 row from `table_name` due to `LIMIT 1`. Remove that bit, so it becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `name`='$row'
```

Comment: removing limit also iterating while loop only once